# Matching Elasticsearch query across many fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of products stored in an index. Assuming the following is an example of a single product:

```
'productID' => 'sandbag'
'productName' => 'Bag of sand'
'productDescription' => 'A bag of sand'
'sizes' => array
    0 =>
        'sizeID' => '1wht'
        'sizeName' => '1 lb white'
    1 =>
        'sizeID' => '1blk'
        'sizeName' => '1 lb black'
    2 =>
        'sizeID' => '2wht'
        'sizeName' => '2 lb white'
    3 =>
        'sizeID' => '2blk'
        'sizeName' => '2 lb black'
```

An ElasticSearch query of **black 1 lb** brings up that product. However, a query of **black 1 lb sand** does not.

If I replace all spaces to AND so the query becomes **black AND 1 AND lb AND sand**, it comes up, however that seems to kill a quoted query such as **"1 lb black" sand**.

My ElasticSearch query looks like:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "black 1 lb sand",
        "default_operator": "AND",
        "fields": ["productName", "sizes.sizeName"]
    }
}
```

Ultimately the goal is to be able to match the sizes and the product name (and anything else I desire) in one query, as well as supporting quoted phrases ("1 lb black") if the customer desires it.

I do not want to switch the operator to OR since that brings up way too many products.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out myself after reading through the docs. Posting here for anyone else that has the same issue in the future.

Simply set the 'type' to 'cross_fields' as detailed at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types

So the search query becomes:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "black 1 lb sand",
        "default_operator": "AND",
        "type": "cross_fields",
        "fields": ["productName", "sizes.sizeName"]
    }
}
```